# Navigating XML via Xpath

Tags: xpath

I am new to Xpath and have been trying to get my head around some basic examples using xpath testing sites before I tackle a much more complex piece.

I am trying to understand exactly how to use the contains function in conjunction with other condition(s), but struggling a bit.

Here is my xml:

```
<root xmlns:foo="http://www.foo.org/" xmlns:bar="http://www.bar.org">
    <actors>
        <actor id="1">Christian Bale</actor>
        <actor id="2">Liam Neeson</actor>
        <actor id="3">Michael Caine</actor>
    </actors>
    <foo:singers>
        <foo:singer id="4">Tom Waits</foo:singer>
        <foo:singer id="4">B.B. King</foo:singer>
        <foo:singer id="6">Ray Charles</foo:singer>
    </foo:singers>
</root>
```

To replicate the type of xml (or html to be more precise) I am trying to parse, I have got one of the singer attributes repeated.

So I am trying to use contains to find the `foo:singer id = 4` and contains `"Tom Waits"`.

From what I have read and examples I have seen, you can use this type of expression:

```
.//*[@id =4 and //foo:singer[contains(text(),'Tom Waits')]]/text()
```

However, this returns both `Tom Waits` and `BB King`.

If I use these two expressions separately, they get the expected results, so not sure exactly if/how they can be combined.

Many thanks if you can assist me.

Andrew

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to pay attention to context. There's no need for the nested predicate.

```
.//*[@id =4 and contains(.,'Tom Waits')]/text()
```

> So I am trying to use contains to find the foo:singer id = 4 and contains "Tom Waits".

Since you're using `//foo:singer` for the contains test, the entire document is in context so it's always true.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
//foo:singer[contains(text(),'Tom Waits')]/text()
```